# Stata ambiguous abbreviation r(111)

Tags: stata

I am trying to draw marginplot using stata12. I am running the following code:

```
margins, at(FuncVariant =(0(0.2) 1)) over(Platform)
```

Following is the error:

> FuncVariant ambiguous abbreviation r(111);

I have the following variables like

```
FuncVariant :
FuncVariant 
FuncVariant_mean
FuncVariant_W
```

Is that creating a problem?

Comment: This should not be a problem. I also can't replicate this error with fake data with your variables names. Please post the exact code and output, including the estimation command, without edits.

Answer (score 1):

Post the exact result of the following command to get a diagnosis of the issue in your data:

```
d FuncVariant*
```

To get rid of the issue, turn the Stata variable abbreviation setting permanently off:

```
set varabbrev off, perm
```

**tl;dr:** you probably don't have a `FuncVariant` variable in your data.

Answer (score 0):

d FuncVariant*

```
          storage  display     value

variable name   type   format      label      variable label
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FuncVariant     byte   %8.0g                  
FuncVariant_m~n float  %9.0g                  
FuncVariant_W   float  %9.0g
```

I understood that FuncVariant is dummy variable, so instead I used FuncVariant_W, but it throws error

```
margins, at( FuncVariant_W =-1(0.2)1) over(Platform)
'FuncVariant_W' not found in list of covariates
```

For many other variables in the dataset it shows the same error, though the variables are present in the dataset.

Comment: This is not complete. Is FuncVariant_W among the covariates in the estimation part, before you invoke margins?